# Object array to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a `List`of objects that I would like to convert to a `byte[]`

My `List` is defined like this:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>
{
     "obj1", "obj2", "obj2"
};
```

Is it possible to convert this list to a `byte[]` in some clean way? The list only contains `base64` strings

All help is appreciated

Comment: Then why isn't `objects` a `List<string>`?

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? Have you considered using one of the serialization mechanisms that the .NET framework provides, e.g. binary or SOAP formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piece of cake:

```
objects.Select(s => Convert.FromBase64String(s)).SelectMany(i => i).ToArray();
```

If `objects` is really a `List<Object>` as @AustinSalonen points out, as opposed to a `List<String>`, you need to make sure that you only have strings first:

```
objects.OfType<String>().Select(s => Convert.FromBase64String(s)).SelectMany(i => i).ToArray();
```

or cast:

```
objects.Cast<String>().Select(s => Convert.FromBase64String(s)).SelectMany(i => i).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I would like all of the data into one big array.

Comment: Thank your very much. I have one last question, what about if the items in the last arent base64 string? If it isn't much truble I would like to se a solution for non base64 items. Is it possible?

Comment: If not base-64 then what are they?  Your original question very specifically stated "The list only contains base64 strings"

Comment: Very sorry for the confusion. The items could be normal strings.

Comment: What format should be used for converting them into bytes?  UTF-8?  ASCII?  Base-64 has special meaning- it means that the characters are an encoded representation of a specific sequence of bytes.  ASCII means something else.  UTF-8 (typically called unicode) means something else again.  You need to be specific.

Comment: @ErikLarsson Then you would have to use the answer the Stanley provided

Comment: I think I`m accepting this one, I originally wantet answer for base64 strings.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for strings:

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;  // Choose the right encoding here
List<byte[]> list = objects.Select(o=>enc.GetBytes(o.ToString()).ToList();
```